# Return type of async method in C#

Tags: c#

How to return something other than void from a async method. Currently i am trying to do this by

```
private static async Task<byte[]>  menu(int len, string data)
```

But this is showing error:

```
The type or namespace name 'Task<byte []>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
```

I am using Visual Studio 2015 CE.

Comment: `using System.Threading.Tasks` ?

Comment: _are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?_

Comment: Start by reading the error message, after that, follow the advice that it's giving you, and if that fails (or you don't understand it), do some research on what that error message means and how to resolve it; there's *lots* of readily available information on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

Include the `System.Threading.Task` namespace by writing `using System.Threading.Task` ontop of your source code file.